# Set Bootstrap cols to 1:1 ratio for height and width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Rails app with a page that has pictures of record covers covering the entire visible background with no spacing. I am allowing users to upload their own images, and I want to ensure that those images are resized when displayed to be exactly 1:1 ratio. If they are not, the tile pattern falls apart and leaves gaps. To do that, I want to size the bootstrap col the picture is inside. I am attempting to do this with JQuery, and am having very little success. Can this be done with JQuery? Is there another way? This is what I have.

Here is my page:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @albums.each do |album| %>
  <a href="/albums/<%= album.id %>">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 index_container embed-responsive-1by1">
      <% if album.cover.blank? %>
        <p><%= album.title %></p>
        <p><%= album.artist %></p>
        <p><%= album.year %></p>
        <%= link_to "Show", album_path(album), class: 'grey' %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_album_path(album), class: 'grey' %>
        <%= link_to "Destroy", album_path(album), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'grey' %>
      <% else %> 
        <%= image_tag album.cover, class: 'index_image' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    </a>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
</div>
<style>
```

Here is my JQuery (which is wrong):

```
<style>
  var cw = $('.index_container').width();
  $('.index_container').css({'height', cw+'px'});
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your CSS, here's what I imagine you have to do:

```
.index_container {
width: 50px; /*or any width you like, but it must be defined*/
height: 50px; /*or any height you like */
background-size: cover /*very important as it covers the element within the defined widthxheight*/;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

And voila - No JQuery needed.